# Execute fabric task for specific host only once

Tags: python, fabric

Im trying to execute main task that needs to execute tasks differently for each host. In the following setup, task 'sometask' will get execute twice for each host. What is the best way to prevent that?

```
@task
@hosts('host1', 'host2')
def test():
    execute(do_something_everywhere)  # execute on both hosts
    execute(sometask, 'arg1', host='host1')  # execute on host1 only
    execute(sometask, 'arg2', host='host2')  # execute on host2 only
```

Comment: is it possible to assign both tasks in two different functions ?

Comment: @Praneeth yes but that would introduce some duplication I'm trying to avoid. For time being I used 2 different functions but wondering if there is a  better way.

Comment: what is the difference between maintask and sometask as argument in the execute ?

Comment: @Praneeth basically sometask does some general stuff to be run across all servers but there are some subtle differences with some nodes. Passed argument would allow to handle those special cases within the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can user the `@runs_once` decorator to remedy this but I find that can cause extra work making wrapper functions to get the execution order you want, so here's a quick fix using the `env.host_string` value to evaluate which server you are deploying to and adjust your script accordingly:

```
@hosts('host1', 'host2')
@task
def checkout(branch='master'):
    execute(_test_task_w_arg, 'all-servers')
    execute(_test_task_w_arg, 'arg1' if env.host_string == 'host1' else 'arg2')

def _test_task_w_arg(arg1):
    local("touch test-file-" + arg1)
```

Results in this output which seems to achieve what you want:

```
    [host1] Executing task 'checkout'
    [localhost] local: touch test-file-all-servers
    [localhost] local: touch test-file-arg1
    [host2] Executing task 'checkout'
    [localhost] local: touch test-file-all-servers
    [localhost] local: touch test-file-arg2
```